# CSS: Can't get background-size: contain to work in Firefox 5

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-5, css

According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) background-size has been supported since Firefox 3.6, however, it is clearly not working in my OS X version of **Firefox 5**. It looks fine in Safari, but **Firefox 5** is not displaying it correctly. Is there a bug? Why can't I get this to work in Firefox?

HTML:

```
<span class="special button">My button</span>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    background-size: contain;
}
.button.special {
    background: url("/images/special-button-bg.png");
}
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nstV7/4/) which shows that it is not working correctly.

Comment: Please post the line of code that is failing.

Comment: `background-size` has only been supported since Firefox 4. Firefox 3.6 uses `-moz-background-size`.

Comment: If it's not displaying correctly I'm sure something must be failing...

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle which shows that it is not working correctly in FF5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on, but it works if you have:

```
.button.special {
    background: url("/images/special-button-bg.png");
    background-size: contain;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nstV7/3/

My guess is that the `background` property is overriding the `background-size` property. However, that doesn't explain why Firefox is not behaving the same as Safari.

Comment: Ah, the pesky shorthand `background` property again.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah, so the CSS3 `background` shorthand is a bit crazy. It only seems to work in Opera..

Comment: Safari's implementation is just buggy; per spec `background` resets `background-size`.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem with this in the follow scenario:
**Win10 + Firefox 55.0.3 64its**, the background-image not showing

I tested with some other browsers and was ok, I could see the image.
eg.: **with Win10 + MS Edge and Win10 + IE11** was working correctly

Because I did not want to use **JavaScript** or **Vendor Prefix** ( -moz- etc. )
I went to  w3c.org trying to search what was wrong, unfortunately I did not found the solution but I decided to try to declare all values:

I changed this:

```
background-size: contain;
```

Into this:

```
background-size: contain contain;
```

I published and tested, and it's working in the following:

1. Win10 + MS Edge
2. Win10 + MS IE 11
3. Win10 + Firefox 55 / 64 bits
4. Win10 + Opera
5. Win Server 2008 + FireFox 55 / 32bits
6. Win Server 2008 + MS IE 11
7. Win Server 2003 + FireFox 52 / 32bits
8. Win Server 2003 + MS IE 6
9. Win 7 + FireFox 54 / 32bits

   10. Win 7 + MS IE 11

I hope this helps someone which wants to avoid the use of Browser Script languages or vendor prefixes.